# Prompting the user for file names in Unix

Tags: unix, if-statement, prompt

I want to write a script which prompts the user for the names of two files, lists the first file on  screen and waits for user to press any key before second file  is listed on the screen. But I am unsure of how to do this. Could anyone help? I think its something like:

```
VALID_FILENAME_ONE="Test1"
VALID_FILENAME_TWO="Test2"

echo "Please enter first file name:"
read file_name1

echo "Please enter second file name:"
read file_name2

if [ "$file_name1" == "$VALID_FILENAME_ONE"]; then
    ls -l |  Test1
else
    echo "No further action"
fi
```

But this does not run correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean, "list"? display the file's contents? the name the user entered?

Comment: Yes lists the files contents in the kernel. Would you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
if [ "$file_name1" == "$VALID_FILENAME_ONE"]; then
```

... add a space between "$VALID_FILENAME_ONE" and the closing square bracket, like this:

```
if [ "$file_name1" == "$VALID_FILENAME_ONE" ]; then
```

Otherwise, bash can't parse your syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am still not achieving the desired results. Would you know how I can get the file names to be listed? I keep getting an error saying `unexpected operator`